# Double-click prevention on save

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with its dataSource, the grid has an editor dialogue with save button. I need to prevent the save button being double clicked. The onsave functions fire when the save button is clicked. I have a requestEnd event that fires when the save is to be re-enabled.

The problem: onSave1 looks to fail 1 time in 100 . It's based on adding an additional click handler, invoking preventDefault(). Is it fundamentally flawed?

Is onSave2 any better?

```
onSave1: function (e) {
    $(event.srcElement)
    .addClass("k-state-disabled")
    .bind("click", disable = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; })
    this.dataSource.one("requestEnd", function () {
        $("[data-role=window] .k-grid-update")
            .off("click", disable)
            .removeClass("k-state-disabled");
    })
}

onSave2: function (e) {     
    $(event.srcElement)
        .removeClass(".k-grid-update")
        .addClass("k-state-disabled")
        .addClass("disabledMarker");
    this.dataSource.one("requestEnd", function () {
        $("[data-role=window] .disabledMarker")
            .addClass(".k-grid-update")
            .removeClass("k-state-disabled")
            .removeClass("disabledMarker");
    })
}
```

Comment: A debounce problem, just disable the button for a few sec after click?

Answer (score 0):

First Jquery bind has been deprecated since version 3.0 so I would recommend not using it anymore. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

You do not need an onClick event or in your case bind because onSave is already being called during the click. So simply disable the button onSave. Second you should use complete or whatever kendo grid uses for when the save event is finished instead or requestEnd. Code listed below.

```
     onSave: {$(event.srcElement)addClass("k-state-disabled")}, complete:{ $(event.srcElement)removeClass("k-state-disabled")};
```

Comment: I believe the k-state-disabled only affects the visual state of the button, not its click-ability - however i will recheck

Comment: onSave1 & onSave2 already incorporate the k-state-disabled add/remove. I already believe onSave1 is unreliable - in that a double click is possible.